# Check Digit Calculator & GTIN-8 Validator

Tags: python, checksum

This program calculates the 7th digit of a GTIN-8 barcode and calculates the validity of an 8 digit GTIN-8 barcode. Could I simplify my code any further?

```
import math 

def roundup(x): 
    return int(math.ceil(x / 10.0)) * 10 

def doMaths(number): 
     count = 0
     total = 0 
     for n in number: 
          n = int(n) 
          if count %2 == 0: 
               total += n * 3 
          else: 
               total += n 
          count += 1
     if len(number) == 8:
          if total %10 == 0: 
               print("Valid")
          else:
               print("Invalid")
     else:
          print(number + str(roundup(total)  - total)) 

while True:
     try:
          number = input("Enter a 7 or 8 digit number for testing: ")
          i = int(number)
          if len(number) == 7 or len(number) == 8:
               doMaths(number)
               break
          else:
               print("Length of number must be 7 or 8")
               continue
     except ValueError:
          print("Only enter numbers.")
          continue
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `doMaths` function has no clear purpose — hence its weird name.  It acts as both to calculate the expected last digit of a 7-digit input and to validate the last digit of an 8-digit input.  Furthermore, it prints its results instead of returning them, hindering reuse of the function.

What you really want to do is share the code that calculates `total`.  You could write a function like this, using [slices](//stackoverflow.com/q/509211/1157100):

```
def gtin8_checksum_digit(number):
    """
    Given a 7- or 8-digit string, calculate the expected GTIN-8 checksum.

    >>> gtin8_checksum_digit('3141592')
    '7'
    >>> gtin8_checksum_digit('31415927')
    '7'
    """
    total = sum(3 * int(d) for d in number[0:7:2]) + \
            sum(int(d) for d in number[1:6:2])
    return str(10 - (total % 10))
```

No floating-point arithmetic should be necessary.

Note the docstring, and in particular, the [doctests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) that make it clear how the function behaves.

To use that function…

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            number = input("Enter a 7 or 8 digit number for testing: ")
            int(number)    # Trigger possible ValueError
            if 7 <= len(number) <= 8: break
            print("Length of number must be 7 or 8")
        except ValueError:
            print("Only enter numbers.")
    if len(number) == 8:
        print("Valid" if gtin8_checksum_digit(number) == number[7] else "Invalid")
    else:
        print(gtin8_checksum_digit(number))
```

Comment: @Graipher That concern did cross my mind. How about Rev 3?

Comment: Definitely better. Although I would put the `break` on its own line for PEP8 compliance.